# Implementing Bootstrap in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I want to make my visualforce page responsive.
I want two column layout to display values of a record.
Just like a detail page(Standard Salesforce page) of any record, Where two-column layout is there.

I am not getting right css or approach.

Comment: Bootstrap provides a complete set of styles for all common page elements and so does Salesforce. They are not designed to work together. Is your goal to just make a standard Salesforce detail page responsive and keep the Salesforce styling as much as possible? Or are you trying to replace the Salesforce styling with Bootstrap styling?

Comment: I am creating a new VF page similar to Detail page but i want to make it responsive and i am not getting how to design two-column layout displaying record values.

Comment: If multi-column layout is your goal, CSS focussed on that problem might be a better place to start - see e.g. http://designinstruct.com/web-design/responsive-css-grid/. I think you should change the title of your question to be specific.

Comment: Adding what code you've already written may help others understand where specificly you need help. Using JS/CSS frameworks are usually best done with disabled SF styles, at that point they shouldn't be that hard to use.

Comment: Are you talking about VF pages with or without Salesforce headers (tabs, standard UI)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Bootstrap for 2 columns and make it responsive use classes "Row" & "col-md-6". Bootstrap site has heavy set of examples and very good documentation on how to use these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this is how you can use bootstrap in your VisualForce page -

```
<apex:page>
  <!-- Adding CSS -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </div>
    </div>
</div>
</apex:page>
```